# Error: Could not find main or io in tokio, invalid return type `impl Future`

Tags: http, rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm on my way of converting to Rust from the ML family, but I'm finding it hard at some strange places I'm not used to having problems.

I'm trying to use `hyper` for http handling but can't seem to get `tokio` to work.

I have tried to copy paste this [example](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/client.rs):

```rust
use hyper::{body::HttpBody as _, Client};
use tokio::io::{self, AsyncWriteExt as _};

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // ...
    fetch_url(url).await
}


async fn fetch_url(url: hyper::Uri) -> Result<()> {
    // ...
    Ok(())
}
```

Here is my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "projectname"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["username"]
edition = "2018"
    
[dependencies]
hyper = "0.14.4"
tokio = "1.2.0"
```

It is complaining that it can't find the `io` crate, and that `main` has an invalid type `impl Future`, and that it can't find `main` in `tokio`:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `main` in `tokio`
 --> src/main.rs:9:10
  |
9 | #[tokio::main]
  |          ^^^^ could not find `main` in `tokio`

error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `impl Future`
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 | async fn main() -> Result<()> {
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^ `main` can only return types that implement `Termination`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `hyper::Client`
 --> src/main.rs:3:34
  |
3 | use hyper::{body::HttpBody as _, Client};
  |                                  ^^^^^^ no `Client` in the root

error[E0425]: cannot find function `stdout` in module `io`
  --> src/main.rs:45:13
   |
45 |         io::stdout().write_all(&chunk).await?;
   |             ^^^^^^ not found in `io`
   |

error[E0432]: unresolved import `tokio::io::AsyncWriteExt`
 --> src/main.rs:4:23
  |
4 | use tokio::io::{self, AsyncWriteExt as _};
  |                       -------------^^^^^
  |                       |
  |                       no `AsyncWriteExt` in `io`
  |                       help: a similar name exists in the module: `AsyncWrite`
```

Is `#[tokio::main]` and `client` not in hyper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tokio::main` macro converts an `async main` to a regular main that spawns a runtime. However, because the macro is not found is scope, it cannot transform your main function, and the compiler is complaining that your main has an invalid return type of `impl Future`. To fix this, you have to enable the required features to import the `main` macro:

```
tokio = { version = "1.2.0", features = ["rt", "macros"] }
```

You also have to enable the `io-util` feature to access `io::AsyncWriteExt`, and the `io-std` feature to access `io::stdout`. To simplify this, `tokio` provides the `full` feature flag, which will enable all optional features:

```
tokio = { version = "1.2.0", features = ["full"] }
```

You also need hyper's `client` and `http` feature flags to resolve the `Client` import:

```rust
hyper = { version = "0.14.4", features = ["client", "http1", "http2"] }
```

Comment: Thanks.. That was helpful, I like rust despite the C++ syntax, which is a minor pain nearly every language use. I think it is the first language in about 40 years that actually not just copied other languages, but took a serious look at the progress in language theory and type systems, and decided that it was time to make a new C with some help to not shoot your own foot off. That it don't support OO, but only 'OO like' is a winning argument. OO is one of the only language features that did not bring anything to the table.